# NIntegrate - why is it much slower in Mathematica 8 in this given case?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I have a Mathematica code where I have to evaluate numerically thousands of integrals similar to this one

```
NIntegrate[
    (Pi*Cos[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)] + (1 + y)*(-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/(1 + y)] + 
    Sin[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)]))/(E^x*(1 + y)), 
    {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}
] //AbsoluteTiming
```

The integrand is a nice absolutely integrable function without singularities, which decays exponentially in one direction and as 1/y^3 in the other direction.

The `NIntegrate` command was working fine in Mathematica 7, but in the newest version 8.0.4 it slows down by two orders of magnitude. I assume in the new version it tries to better control the error, but at the expense of this tremendous increase in time. Are there some settings I could use so that the computation proceeds with the same speed as in Mathematica 7?

Comment: Here (on 8.0.1) it complains about a "catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate" and returns unevaluated.

Comment: On 8.0.4 it does not complain, but takes over 300 seconds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**ruebenko**'s answer and the comments from **user1091201** and **Leonid** together combine to give the right answers.

The **Edit 1** answer by **ruebenko** is the right first answer for *general* situations like this, that is, add the option `Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "OscillatorySelection" -> False}`:

```
expr = (Pi*
      Cos[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)] + (1 + y)*(-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/(1 + y)] +
         Sin[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)]))/(E^x*(1 + y));

NIntegrate[expr, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", 
    "OscillatorySelection" -> False}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

And **user1091201**'s comment suggesting `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"` is close to the fastest possible answer for *this specific* problem.

I'll describe what is happening in NIntegrate in this specific example and along the way give some tips on handling apparently similar situations in general.

**Method Selection**

In this example, NIntegrate examines `expr`, comes to the conclusion that multidimensional "LevinRule" is the best method for this integrand, and applies it. However, for this particular example, "LevinRule" is slower than "MultidimensionalRule" (though "LevinRule" gets a more satisfactory error estimate). "LevinRule" is also slower than any of several Gauss-type one-dimensional rules iterated over the two dimensions, such as "GaussKronrodRule" which **user1091201** found.

NIntegrate makes its decision after performing some symbolic analysis of the integrand. There are several types of symbolic pre-processing applied; the setting  `Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "OscillatorySelection" -> False}` disables one type of symbolic pre-processing.

Essentially, with "OscillatorySelection" enabled, NIntegrate selects "LevinRule". With "OscillatorySelection" disabled, NIntegrate selects "MultidimensionalRule", which is faster for this integral, although we may distrust the result based the message NIntegrate::slwcon which indicates unusually slow convergence was observed.

This is the part where Mathematica 8 differs from Mathematica 7: Mathematica 8 adds "LevinRule" and associated method selection heuristics into "OscillatorySelection".

Aside from causing NIntegrate to select a different method, disabling "OscillatorySelection" also saves the time spent doing the actual symbolic processing, which can be significant in some cases.

Setting `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"` overrides and skips the symbolic processing associated with method selection, and instead uses the 2-D cartesian product rule `Method -> {"CartesianRule", Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "GaussKronrodRule"}}`. This happens to be a very fast method for this integral.

**Other Symbolic Processing**

Both **ruebenko**'s `Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "OscillatorySelection" -> False}` and  **user1091201**'s `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"` do not disable other forms of symbolic processing, and this is generally a good thing. See [this part of the NIntegrate advanced documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntroduction.html#118305364) for a list of types of symbolic preprocessing that may be applied. In particular, "SymbolicPiecewiseSubdivision" is very valuable for integrands that are non-analytic at several points due to the presence of piecewise functions.

To disable *all* symbolic processing and get only default methods with default method options, use `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`. For one-dimensional integrals this currently amounts to `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}` with certain default settings for all parameters of those methods (number of interpolation points in the rule, type of singularity handling for the global-adaptive strategy, etc). For multi-dimensional integrals, it currently amounts to `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "MultidimensionalRule"}`, again with certain default parameter values. For high-dimensional integrals, a monte-carlo method will be used.

I don't recommend switching straight to `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` as a first optimization step for NIntegrate, but it can be useful in some cases.

**Fastest method**

There is just about **always** some way to speed up a numerical integration at least a bit, sometimes a lot, since there are so many parameters that are chosen heuristically that you may benefit from tweaking. (Look at the different options and parameters that the ["LevinRule" method](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337) or the ["GlobalAdaptive" strategy](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#137878679) has, including all their sub-methods etc.)

That said, here is the fastest method I found for this particular integral:

```
NIntegrate[(Pi*
      Cos[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)] + (1 + y)*(-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/(1 + y)] +
         Sin[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)]))/(E^x*(1 + y)), {x, 0, 
   100}, {y, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
    "SingularityDepth" -> Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

(The setting `"SingularityDepth" -> Infinity` disables singularity handling transformations.)

**Integration range**

By the way, is your desired integration range really `{x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}`, or is `{x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}` the true desired integration range for your application?

If you really require `{x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}`, I suggest using that instead. For infinite-length integration ranges, NIntegrate compactifies the integrand to a finite range, effectively samples it in a geometrically-spaced way. This is usually much more efficient than linear (evenly) spaced samples that are used for finite integration ranges.

Comment: Yes, indeed {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity} is the required range. Thanks for pointing this out. I was including the contribution from y>100 by series expansion combined with analytic integration. I thought this was more reliable.

Comment: Ah yes that can be a good maneuver. It can also work well in the other direction: If you really want a finite-range integration, form it as the difference of two infinite range integrations, or as the difference of an infinite range integration and a series expansion of the tail.

Comment: Hello Andrew, we have a proposal for a [separate Mathematica site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=hWeRiD9Qz0oIDM_9uBjtlA2) under the SE network, for anything related to mma (not just programming questions like on SO). We're very close to launching (24 users remaining) and it would be great if you could commit to that proposal :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a workaround:

```
NIntegrate[(Pi*
      Cos[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)] + (1 + y)*(-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/(1 + y)] +
         Sin[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)]))/(E^x*(1 + y)), {x, 0, 
   100}, {y, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

You can also use ParallelTry to tests various methods in parallel.

Slowdowns for specific arguments can happen when new methods are implemented or heuristics are modified. Those may help to solve a new class of problems at the expense that some others get slower. One would have to investigate exactly what is going on here.

You might want to change the topic of your question - it indicates that all integrals evaluate slower in V8 which is not true.

**Edit 1**:
I think it get's stuck in LevinRule (new in V8 for oscillatory integrands) so, I think, this should switch that off.

```
NIntegrate[(Pi*
      Cos[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)] + (1 + y)*(-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/(1 + y)] +
         Sin[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)]))/(E^x*(1 + y)), {x, 0, 
   100}, {y, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", 
    "OscillatorySelection" -> False}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: The situation is more complex. Your code was the first thing I also tried, but unfortunately it does not give the correct result (at least on M8.0, which I used for it), and it does not even give the same result when ran several times. The problem is that the integrand is not so innocent - it decays very fast in one dimension and also is highly oscilating.

Comment: I think it gets stuck in LevinRule. So edit 1 should help to work around that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. By forcing it to use a specific method, such as Method -> "GaussKronrodRule" it may take as little as 0.2 seconds (on my laptop), while using Method -> "LevinRule" takes 343 s while producing the same result. Probably not specifying method tries several of them.

Comment: Be careful with a specific method - like my first try above it went wrong. The second approach is better since it switches off a specific approach. But again LevinRule is made for this type of problem and can deliver better results. It is always more important to give the right result then a wrong result very fast.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular integral, the main culprit seems to be the integration over `x`, probably due to the presence of both fast-decaying and highly-oscillating terms. Also, for this case,  one can do the integration over `x` analytically:

```
In[92]:= 
-Integrate[(Pi*Cos[(Pi*(-2*x+y))/(1+y)]+(1+y)*(-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/(1+y)]+Sin[(Pi*(-2*x+y))/(1+y)]))/
 (E^x*  (1+y)),x]/.x->0//FullSimplify

Out[92]= (-\[Pi] (1+y) (2+Cos[(\[Pi] y)/(1+y)])+(2 \[Pi]^2+(1+y)^2) Sin[(\[Pi] y)/(1+y)])/
(4 \[Pi]^2+(1+y)^2)
```

(I discarded the value on the upper limit, since it is uniformly very small for `y`). One can then integrate over `y` numerically to get the right result:

```
In[94]:= NIntegrate[%,{y,0,100}]
Out[94]= 1.17525
```

A more general workaround would be to split the `x` and `y` integration like so:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[y_?NumericQ, xrange : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] :=
  NIntegrate[(Pi*
   Cos[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)] + (1 + 
     y)*(-Sin[(2*Pi*x)/(1 + y)] + 
     Sin[(Pi*(-2*x + y))/(1 + y)]))/(E^x*(1 + y)), {x, First@xrange, Last@xrange}];
```

and then we have:

```
In[105]:= NIntegrate[f[y,{0,100}],{y,0,100}]//Timing
Out[105]= {2.578,1.17525}
```

which is not blazing fast, but reasonably fast. This procedure won't always work so well (since the 2D integration grid resulting from this procedure won't always be optimal), but should work well enough when the integrand is such that integrations over `x` and `y` are sufficiently "decoupled".