# How can I speed up NIntegrate computation?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I want to plot a definite integral

```
myIntegral[x_] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + (c - d)^2]/ (a - b), {a, 0, x}, {b, x, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}]
Plot[myIntegral[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I am using Mathematica 11.3. When I evaluate the code, Mathematica immediately gives some warnings about numerical integration converging too slowly, then it seems stuck in computation.
I have tried some options of NIntegrate, for example as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456800/nintegrate-why-is-it-much-slower-in-mathematica-8-in-this-given-case), but have had no success.
Is there a way to obtain the result of Plot in an acceptable time (e.g. some minutes)?

Comment: You'll get better help if you post your question on the [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I copied my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175622/how-can-i-speed-up-nintegrate-computation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is within reach of `Integrate`.

```
Assuming[0<x<1,
 Simplify[
   Integrate[Sqrt[(a-b)^2 + (c-d)^2]/(a-b), {a,0,x}, {b,x,1}, {c,0,1}, {d,0,1}]]]
```

which gives you

```
(-11*Sqrt[2] + 11*Sqrt[2+(-2+x)*x] + x*(-8-7*Sqrt[2+(-2+x)*x] + 13*Sqrt[1+x^2] +
 2*x*(6-3*Sqrt[2+(-2+x)*x] + x*(-4+2*x + Sqrt[2+(-2+x)*x] - Sqrt[1+x^2]))) +
 18*x^2*ArcCoth[Sqrt[2+(-2+x)*x]] + 9*ArcSinh[1] - 3*ArcSinh[1-x] - 3*ArcSinh[x] +
 6*Log[1-x] + 9*x*Log[-1+Sqrt[2+(-2+x)*x]] + 3*((-2+x)*Log[1+Sqrt[2+(-2+x)*x]] -
 4*x*Log[-(((-1+x)*(1 + Sqrt[1+x^2]))/x)] + x^3*(Log[2+x^2+2*Sqrt[1+x^2]] +
 2*Log[(1-x)/(x+x*Sqrt[2-2*x+x^2])])))/36
```

And that should be much faster to plot than doing thousands on individual `NIntegrate`